# Setting variables based off an object

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, switch-statement

I have an object which could include a mix of properties e.g.

```
{a: 1}, {b: 4}, {c: 2}, {a: 3, b: 1}
```

it will be a key with a count value next to it.

I'd like to set a bunch of variables depending on which key names are in the object, for instance:

```
aOnly = {a: 1}, mixOfAB = {a: 3, b: 1}
```

I'm using this logic in a function which will eventually return a string value. What's the best way to operate on this object, I tried using a switch but it didn't work so well. I could use a large number of if/else statements but is there something more neater?

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to set a bunch of variables (which must be computed at runtime) as you won't be able to easily refer to them later in your code due to not knowing which ones exist. Can you describe what the goal is here a bit more?

Comment: This code will be in a function which will return a string back to where it's being called. I can make it work by checking each property of the object using lots of if/else conditions, just wondered if there is a smarter/more efficient way.

Comment: What string will be returned? Can you give some examples of input => desired output ?

Comment: Examples of input objects in first line of code.

Output would be as 2nd line, to make it clearer though, 'aOnly' would only have a value of true if the object only contained the key 'a' as in code above.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
vars = {}

function setVariable(obj) {
    keys = Object.keys(obj)
    name = keys.length == 1 ? keys[0] + 'Only' : 'mixOf' + keys.join('').toUpperCase()
    vars[name] = obj
}

setVariable({a: 1})
console.log(vars)

setVariable({b: 4})
console.log(vars)

setVariable({c: 2})
console.log(vars)

setVariable({a: 3, b: 1})
console.log(vars)
```

Comment: It's not an array of objects - it would be a single object with 1 or more keys. Depending on which keys are present I would set a particular value.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect what I think you're describing. The input is your array of sample objects, but we act on each object individually and produce the var for it.

Comment: Again, there is no array - anywhere. I said in the previous comment, it's just a single object.

Comment: Can you clarify what the single object is from your question description? `{a: 1}, {b: 4}, {c: 2}, {a: 3, b: 1}` looks like an array of sample objects, but I seem to be misinterpreting your intention with that. The answer attempts to provide a way to produce the desired variable for each of the samples in your question.

Comment: I've updated the answer to remove the reference to the list and just call a setVariable method to avoid confusion around the purpose of the list.

Comment: On the first line of the question I mention an object, no arrays, and the second line is examples of what the object could be, hopefully that clears any confusion.

I'm trying a few different approaches, will give yours a try too, thanks.